# CollectionView does not work when embedded in Navigation Controller

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3

I have a simple collection view test (based on an online tutorial) which works fine stand alone. But when I embed it in a navigation controller it stops working. I built the screen in code by (1) creating a headerView (64 pixel high) and added it to the view at the top. (2) I built a collection view and added it to the headerView.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,
UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UINavigationControllerDelegate
{
var collectionView : UICollectionView!
var topView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var frame = CGRect(x:0,y:128, width:view.frame.width, height:64)
    topView = UIView(frame:frame)
    self.view.addSubview(topView)

    // CollectionView
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)

    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(self.topView.frame.width), height: Int(self.topView.frame.height))
    collectionView = UICollectionView (frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    self.topView.addSubview(collectionView)

}

//MARK: - CollectionView

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 14
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    for v in cell.subviews {
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0 , width:50 , height:50))
    label.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.addSubview(label)

    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: I had limited the height of the top view which has the collection view as a sub-view to 64 (to force a single row). When I increase the height of the top view to 128 the cells show up in the second row. It is not clear to me why the navigation controller has anything to do with forcing the cells into a lower row. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do n't set the frame manually for collectionview, try this code instead  collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout) collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin,.flexibleLeftMargin,.flexibleBottomMargin,.flexibleRightMargin,  .flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth] collectionView.setNeedsDisplay() //move all collection view code in viewdidAppear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't make Kaushal's suggestion work as stated. It did give me a clue that my positioning of the view in which I had embedded the collection view was being misplaced in viewDidLoad for reasons that I have not understood. However by putting the collection view configuration in viewDidAppear (rather than viewDidLoad) it worked well. I offset the y position by 64 to clear the navbar, and I reduced the row height to 64. I also, put code to execute the code only once so that navigating from pages does not add multiple views of top of each other. BTW, my original objective was to have horizontally scrolling cells. In my program I have tableview with corresponding sections and the idea is to use the row with horizontally scrolling cells to move to a corresponding section.

The code is shown below:

```
    //
//  CustomViewController.swift
//  DSM Tracker
//
//  Created by Syed Tariq on 1/7/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 com.syedtariq. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,
    UICollectionViewDelegate,
    UICollectionViewDataSource,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate

{

    var executeOnce = true
    var cellDimensions = [String:Int]()
    var cellHeight = 50
    var cellWidth = 120

    var collectionContainerView: UICollectionView!
    var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar()


    // view constants
    var viewY = CGFloat()
    var viewX = CGFloat()
    var viewWidth = CGFloat()
    var viewHeight = CGFloat()


    // gaps from view edge
    let leftGap = CGFloat(20)
    let rightGap = CGFloat(20)


    // navbar constants
    let navBarHeight = CGFloat(64)

    var headerLabels = ["Cell 01","Cell 02","Cell 03","Cell 04","Cell 05","Cell 06","Cell 07","Cell 08","Cell 09","Cell 10","Cell 11","Cell 12","Cell 13","Cell 14","Cell 15","Cell 16"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        executeOnce = true
        viewY = view.frame.origin.y
        viewX = view.frame.origin.x
        viewWidth = view.frame.width
        viewHeight = view.frame.height
    }



    func configureCollectionView () {
        if executeOnce {
            executeOnce = false
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)

            let colWidth = viewWidth - leftGap - rightGap
            let colX = viewX + leftGap
            let colY = viewY + navBarHeight
            let colHeight = CGFloat(64)
            let frame = CGRect(x:colX, y:colY, width: colWidth, height: colHeight)
            //let frame = CGRect.zero
            collectionContainerView = UICollectionView (frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            collectionContainerView.dataSource = self
            collectionContainerView.delegate = self
            collectionContainerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin,.flexibleLeftMargin,.flexibleBottomMargin,.flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
            collectionContainerView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
            collectionContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            collectionContainerView.allowsSelection = true
            collectionContainerView.isScrollEnabled = true
            collectionContainerView.setNeedsDisplay()
            print("collectionContainerView.frame \(collectionContainerView.frame)")
            view.addSubview(collectionContainerView)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        configureCollectionView()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("headerLabels.count \(headerLabels.count)")
        return  headerLabels.count
    }



    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

        for v in cell.subviews {
            v.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let cellTitle = headerLabels[indexPath.row]
        let cellTitleLines = cellTitle.components(separatedBy: " ")
        let nLabels = cellTitleLines.count

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        let labelHeight = cellHeight / cellTitleLines.count
        for i in (0 ..< nLabels) {
            let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: labelHeight * i, width: cellWidth, height: labelHeight)
            let label1 = UILabel(frame: frame)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            label1.numberOfLines = 1
            label1.text = headerLabels[indexPath.row]
            label1.textAlignment = .center
            label1.textColor = UIColor.black
            label1.clipsToBounds = true
            label1.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label1.text = cellTitleLines[i]
            cell.addSubview(label1)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        collectionContainerView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

        return true
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionContainerView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        print("cell = \(cell)")
        collectionContainerView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: indexPath.item, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didHighlightItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    }
}
```